# Cannot upload audio file but images works fine

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am attempting to set up a simple file upload using w3schools file upload to upload audio with

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "mp3" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="<?php echo WEB_ROOT ?>components/includes/_int/su.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sTitle">Song Title</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="sTitle" type="text" id="sTitle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sGenre">Genre</label>
                    <select id="sGenre" name="sGenre" class="selectpicker form-control">
                        <?php foreach (genre::GetGenresT() as $genre) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php $genre->PrintID(); ?>"><?php $genre->PrintName(); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sArtist">Artist</label>
                    <select id="sArtist" name="sArtist" class="selectpicker form-control">
                        <?php foreach (artist::GetArtists() as $artist) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php $artist->PrintID(); ?>"><?php $artist->PrintName(); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sLyrics">Lyric</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control">sadsadas</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="file">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Cancel</a>
                    <button name="btn-submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

As you'll see en the PHP code i've added a "&& $imageFileType != "mp3" and the only error I get is the "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file." error. 
it seems to be going through everything fine until it needs to upload no other errors.

It uploads images just fine but mp3 files it just wont do it. I've tried to find other examples but everything leading to the same issue. If someone can explain why it's doing this it would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking for an image file type in your initial check which is why your audio is failing. The MIME type is different for mp3, it's 'audio/mpeg' as opposed to jpg/png/gif which is the what the image MIME type checks for. Ideally you should check for an array of MIME types in your php (and go from there).. There's a good example in the user notes on the [php website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

The example posted reads

```
if(!function_exists('mime_content_type')) {

    function mime_content_type($filename) {

        $mime_types = array(

            'txt' => 'text/plain',
            'htm' => 'text/html',
            'html' => 'text/html',
            'php' => 'text/html',
            'css' => 'text/css',
            'js' => 'application/javascript',
            'json' => 'application/json',
            'xml' => 'application/xml',
            'swf' => 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
            'flv' => 'video/x-flv',

            // images
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
            'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
            'ico' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
            'tiff' => 'image/tiff',
            'tif' => 'image/tiff',
            'svg' => 'image/svg+xml',
            'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml',

            // archives
            'zip' => 'application/zip',
            'rar' => 'application/x-rar-compressed',
            'exe' => 'application/x-msdownload',
            'msi' => 'application/x-msdownload',
            'cab' => 'application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed',

            // audio/video
            'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
            'qt' => 'video/quicktime',
            'mov' => 'video/quicktime',

            // adobe
            'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
            'psd' => 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop',
            'ai' => 'application/postscript',
            'eps' => 'application/postscript',
            'ps' => 'application/postscript',

            // ms office
            'doc' => 'application/msword',
            'rtf' => 'application/rtf',
            'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',

            // open office
            'odt' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
            'ods' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
        );

        $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename)));
        if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)) {
            return $mime_types[$ext];
        }
        elseif (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
            finfo_close($finfo);
            return $mimetype;
        }
        else {
            return 'application/octet-stream';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

A bit long winded in your case! You could shorten it significantly to

```
if(!function_exists('mime_content_type')) {

    function mime_content_type($filename) {

        $mime_types = array(

            // images
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
            'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
            'ico' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
            'tiff' => 'image/tiff',
            'tif' => 'image/tiff',
            'svg' => 'image/svg+xml',
            'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml',

            // audio/video
            'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
            'qt' => 'video/quicktime',
            'mov' => 'video/quicktime',


        );

        $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename)));
        if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)) {
            return $mime_types[$ext];
        }
        elseif (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
            finfo_close($finfo);
            return $mimetype;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

i.e. omit the types you don't want! :)

Hope this helps

EDIT: Of course, instead of checking the image size, (getimagesize) you could just check for the filesize instead and then check the extensions after with something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

A lot handier!

Comment: Ah yes I see! Thank you very much :)